# Getting started with a Windows Store app

Tags: visual-studio, windows-store-apps, virtual-machine

I'm looking to get started on a pretty simple Windows Store app. It'll be distributed inside a business, not public (there's a more specific way to say that but...). It seems you can't get past the very first step of installing Visual Studio if you aren't on Windows 8.1. I have a Win8 device (a Surface Pro 3), but I'd be more comfortable developing on my Windows 7 Desktop. Long question to say, do I have to purchase a Windows 8 license to run a VM on my Desktop for development? Or is there an easier way to get Visual Studio installed and started? Windows Dev guidelines, just kinda jump over that little step...

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you would keep a 5 year old OS on your desktop, but you do need Windows 8 to do Windows 8 development. Not sure if there's any way to develop on Windows 7 and do remote debugging to a Windows 8 device - I doubt that, but that would be much more painful anyway than debugging on your dev box.

Comment: I keep Win 7 because I know it works with the software I run, mostly for motion design like After Effects and Cinema 4D. Windows 8 might be just as great, but I don't want to rock the boat for no reason, and my desktop isn't touch enabled, so virtually no gains... I guess I can get pick up a copy of 8 for my VM, I just wanted to make sure there's not a really easy way that I'm overlooking.

Comment: Not sure why your software would stop working with Windows 8. Generally I haven't seen problems with any apps after upgrading to 8 and the upgrade is cheap and really straightforward, though of course there might be some special cases for specific apps. I wouldn't call this a "no reason" - since you want to develop an app for Windows 8 - apparently there is a reason. Touch support isn't the main gain of Windows 8. It's better for many other small reasons and from what I recall - it just runs faster, boots faster etc. I may be biased though.

Comment: Thanks again, I'll consider upgrading, but that does take time and effort that running VM wouldn't. But you're right, if I'm making apps for Windows 8 why not use it.

Comment: Rather than VM I would recommend boot to VHD. It makes your machine work just about the same as if you had actually installed the OS on your drive, whereas VMs can be painfully slow.

Comment: Interesting! No I hadn't considered a VHD. I'm definitely gonna look into that! This is exactly why I asked the question, I know that not all developers are on Windows 8, if anything there has to be a huge community on Macbook's doing this work. Thank you for that input, I'll test out VHD once I get my 8.1 license from my client.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need a license even for VM. However, Microsoft has the best support for developers and you can find some programm that will be suitable for you. BizSpark, DreamSpark, AzureCloud etc. Maybe you'll be able to get all the software for free. 
Regarding the new system, Windows 8 is same as Windows 7 in desktop mode. Except start menu. So, you can install Pokki or Start8 to 'fix' it.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to comment! I'm excited to get started on the project, because it does look like Microsoft is really supporting development! I'm not looking for a new system, and it's not worth my time to update to 8. I'm on a rock solid system that has never let me down, and I'm not gonna update and take any chances. That's why they make VM's :)

Comment: For my taste, coding in VM is a pain. I have top new core i5, 16gb ram? SSDs and vm still laggy and not so slick as a real machine :) Only Vm with disk in ram looks acceptable.

Comment: I hadn't considered lag... I haven't gotten into it much yet, in the few minutes I messed with the Win10 Preview, I didn't notice any. Not to get into a hardware contest with you, but I do have 32gb ram and overclocked i7. I hope I don't see it, but if I do, I guess I'll be working on my Surface Pro 3.

Comment: Which one VM software do you use?

Comment: Oracle VM VirtualBox currently. Seems to be one of the easiest to set up.